# sqlite select difference between 2 tables

Tags: sqlite, select

table1 has columns A1,B1,C1 and table2 has columns A2,B2,C2 where A1 and A2 refer to the same thing, and B1 and B2 refer to the same thing.

How do I find rows in table1 such that the equivalent rows in table2 (A2=A1, B2=B1) are not in table1, and vice versa?

is it an EXCEPT?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` like

```
select A1, B1, C1 
from table1
where not exists 
(
select 1 from table2
where A2 = table1.A1
and B2 = table1.B1
)
```